# Linux CLion can't resolve namespace member

Tags: c++, linux, std, archlinux, clion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    std::srand( time(0) );

    return 0;
}
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAcKn.png)

This code compiles and run fine. But error messsage doesn't disappear and it annoys me. Maybe someone solved this problem.

My system info.

```
Linux desktop 4.6.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 11 19:12:32 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux

g++ (GCC) 6.1.1 20160707
```

P.S. The problem appears with included cstdlib. I think the problem in the IDE.

Comment: I rolled back the edit because it changed the question. If you are sure the change results in the same warning, you could add a note about that and I can remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using C++ 11 < random >

Answer (score 0):

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-7573
According to the bugtracker, it is supposed to be fixed in "2016.3.2 EAP"