# Clion IDE C++ false positive on syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, clion

I am using Clion as IDE

I just updated my fedora from 24 to 25 in order to use C++17,
But unfortunately now, CLion (v 2017.2.3) display code error that wasn't there before the OS upgrade

Here an "error" shown using template argument as template for `std::optional`

[image]

Here an "error" shown using `std::make_shared`, saying I am using too many argument (I should need 2 apparently) while the actual constructor takes 3 argument. I remind that the code compile and works

[image]

My CMake file (dunno if it could help for this)

```
Cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(FreeSouls CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lprotobuf -lboost_timer -lboost_system -lboost_thread")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

if ( UNIX )
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
            "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Wno-deprecated-declarations")
    message( STATUS Set Warnings flag : ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
endif()

enable_testing()

add_subdirectory( Protobuff )

include_directories(
        cmake-build-debug/Protobuff
        FySMQ/include/queue
        FySMQ/include/bus
        FySMemoryManager/include
        Server/include/gateway
        Server/include/network
        Server/include/babble
        Server/include/game Utils/src)

set(SOURCE_FILES_MM)

set(SOURCE_PROTOBUF
        cmake-build-debug/Protobuff/FySBabbleMessage.pb.cc
        cmake-build-debug/Protobuff/FySGtwMessage.pb.cc
        cmake-build-debug/Protobuff/FySLoginMessage.pb.cc
        cmake-build-debug/Protobuff/FySAuthenticationResponse.pb.cc
)

set(SOURCE_FILES_MQ
        FySMQ/include/queue/LockFreeQueue.hh
        FySMQ/include/queue/QueueContainer.hh
        FySMQ/include/queue/LockingQueue.hh
        FySMQ/include/bus/BusListener.hh
        FySMQ/include/bus/FysBus.hh)

set(SOURCE_FILES_SRV
        Server/src/gateway/Gateway.cpp
        Server/include/gateway/Gateway.hh
        Server/src/gateway/Context.cpp
        Server/include/gateway/Context.hh
        Server/src/network/SessionManager.cpp
        Server/include/network/SessionManager.hh
        Server/src/babble/Babble.cpp
        Server/include/babble/Babble.hh
        Server/src/babble/BabbleChannel.cpp
        Server/include/babble/BabbleChannel.hh
        Server/src/network/TcpConnection.cpp
        Server/include/network/TcpConnection.hh
        Server/src/gateway/GameServerInstance.cpp
        Server/include/gateway/GameServerInstance.hh
        Server/src/gateway/Authenticator.cpp
        Server/include/gateway/Authenticator.hh
)

set(SOURCE_FILES_UTILS Utils/src/CheckVars.hh Utils/src/TokenGenerator.cpp Utils/src/TokenGenerator.hh)

set(SOURCE_FILES_ALL
        ${SOURCE_PROTOBUF}
        ${SOURCE_FILES_UTILS}
        ${SOURCE_FILES_MQ}
        ${SOURCE_FILES_MM}
        ${SOURCE_FILES_SRV})

set(SOURCE_FILES
        ${SOURCE_FILES_ALL}
        Server/src/main.cpp)

set(SOURCE_FILES_TEST
        ${SOURCE_FILES_ALL}
        FySMQ/test/TestUnitMQ.cpp
        Utils/test/TestCheckVar.cpp
        FySMQ/test/FysBusTest.hh)

### Server ###
add_executable(FreeSouls ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(FreeSouls proto )

# link against dynamic libraries
add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK)

## Test executable
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
add_executable(UnitTests ${SOURCE_FILES_TEST})
target_link_libraries(UnitTests ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})
add_test(UnitTests UnitTests)
```

Does this error ever happened to you? How can I fix that?

I found a post about a problem similar here 
[Linux CLion can't resolve namespace member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674349/linux-clion-cant-resolve-namespace-member)
But it looked like it were a bug of the Clion and a new version fixed it,
knowing I was using the exact same version on fedora 24 and it was working fine before the upgrade, I don't know if it is the same.

Comment: Is it compiling? If so, then it's likely just a CLion parser bug

Comment: Yes, it certainly is, but the fact I don't find any recent ticket about this makes me wonder if its not just something that has to be added in the CMakeList in order to indicate the use of C++17 to Clion or something. The fact is, it was working perfectly before, which mean the only difference now is the fact I compile this code with C++17

Comment: I believe CLion's parser is standard-agnostic, much like MSVC was until recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Chris, this was a bug from the CLion parser.
The release of the version 2017.3 has solved those issues.